# Как снять ограничения, для одного пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы только пользователь, которому адресована капча мог снять ограничения, а не любой юзер. Скажем, капча адресована для Екатерины (пользователь, которому запрещено писать), но при этом другой пользователь может нажать на кнопку и все ограничения снимаются. Как это исправить?

Я долго лепил этот код, несколько человек с разных сайтов оказали мне помощь, один человек даже целый день правил код, я же потом просто немного его улучшил, пользуясь информацией, которую читал по различным сайтам.

Я видел в группах боты, в которых эта функция работает корректно. Например, после нажатия на чужую капчу мне написал бот: "Эта капча не для Вас".

Мой код идеально работает, но существует такой недочет.

```
#База Данных
conn = sqlite3.connect("misqlite.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, user_id INTEGER, username TEXT, name TEXT, last_name TEXT, chat_id INTEGER)''')
conn.commit()
#conn.close()

class SQLither:

    def __init__(self, database) -> object:
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()


    def exists_user_chat(self, user_id, chat_id):
        """Проверка существования пользователя в БД и в группе"""
        #return bool(self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,)).fetchone())
        return bool(self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=? and chat_id=?", (user_id, chat_id,)).fetchone())

    def add_to_db(self, user_id, username, name, last_name, chat_id):
        """Добавление пользователя в БД"""
        #self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('user_id') VALUES(?)", (user_id,)) and self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('username') VALUES(?)", (username,))
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id, username, name, last_name, chat_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", (user_id, username, name, last_name, chat_id))
        self.conn.commit()

db = SQLither("misqlite.db")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def inline_menu(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<b>\nНажми кнопку.</b>'.format(message.from_user), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=menu)
    return
```

Рабочий код

```html
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def handler_text(message: types.Message):
    member = await bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)
    if member.user.username == 'GroupAnonymousBot':
    #if member.user.first_name == 'Group':
        return

    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    last_name = message.from_user.last_name
    name = message.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    if not db.exists_user_chat(user_id, chat_id):
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            checkYes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я не робот!', callback_data=f'captcha:{user_id}')
            keyboard.add(checkYes)
            msg = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"<a href=\"tg://user?id={user_id}\">{name}</a>. нажми кнопку.".format(message.from_user), parse_mode='html', disable_notification=True, disable_web_page_preview=True, reply_markup = keyboard)
            asyncio.create_task(delete_message(msg, 180))
            await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_other_messages=False, can_add_web_page_previews=False, can_send_polls=False, can_pin_messages=False, disable_notification=True, can_invite_users=True))
            await message.delete()
            db.add_to_db(message.from_user.id, username, name, last_name, message.chat.id)
            return


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='captcha')
async def captcha(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = str(call.from_user.id)
    to_id = call.data.split(':')[1]

    username = call.from_user.username
    last_name = call.from_user.last_name
    name = call.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    
    if not db.exists_user_chat(user_id, chat_id):
        db.add_to_db(call.from_user.id, username, name, last_name, call.message.chat.id)

    member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=call.from_user.id)
    if user_id in to_id:
    #if member.status in member_statuses:
        await call.answer(text="Спасибо)", show_alert=True)
        #await call.message.delete()
        await bot.restrict_chat_member(call.message.chat.id, call.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True, can_send_media_messages=True, can_send_other_messages=True, can_add_web_page_previews=True, can_send_polls=True, can_pin_messages=True, can_invite_users=True, can_change_info=True))
    else:
        await call.answer(text="Не принято", show_alert=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать, храня данные об адресате в inline-кнопке. Например, вместо `callback_data = 'captcha'`, мы сделаем `callback_data = f'captcha:{id пользователя}'`. Далее в хендлере мы достаем этот id (это можно сделать с помощью `split`) и сравниваем его с id пользователя, нажавшего на кнопку.

Вот как это выглядит в коде:

```
def captcha(user_id: int) -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup: #генерация клавиатуры
    
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                'Я не робот!', 
                callback_data=f'captcha:{user_id}',
            ),
        ],
    )
    return markup


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def captcha(message: types.Message):
    
    await message.answer(
        '<b>Нажми на кнопку!</b>',
        reply_markup=captcha(message.from_user.id),
    )


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='captcha')
async def check(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    user_id = str(call.from_user.id)
    to_id = call.data.split(':')[1]

    if user_id == to_id:  # сверяем id в кнопке с id нажавшего

        await call.message.edit_text(
            'Капча пройдена!',
        )
        # разблокируем возможность писать

    else:

        await call.answer(
            'Это не ваша капча!',
            True,
        )
```

Comment: Ругается, на эту строку to_id = call.data.split(':')[1]
ошибка при нажатии
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Покажи мне callback кнопки (``print(call.data)``)

Comment: Супер, теперь все работает, сам не пойму, что слепил, все заработало.

Comment: Новую кнопку сгенерировал, наверное

Comment: В вопросе допишу, весь рабочий код.

Comment: А можно ли, по кнопке, сделать проверку приглашения контактов, например, если пользователь, пригласил минимум 10, стена откроется и сможет разместить одну публикация?

Comment: Это нужно тыкать бд, после проверки там разблокировать доступ. После поста автоматом сделать закрытие доступа

Comment: Подскажите, как это все прописать, для бд и для @callback_query_handler а так же, если надо, для @dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
Я не могу сам сделать, не очень опытный в пайтоне

Comment: Нужно так, например пользователь опубликовал, сразу же удаляется, доступ закрывается и кнопка с текстов, пригласите от 20 контактов в группу и нажми кнопку, для проверки. И так по кругу, 1 пост удаляется, приглашаются участники в группу, из списка контактов, нажимается кнопка, для проверки и если все хорошо, пользователь сможет опубликовать 1 публикацию.